# adding InfoWindow in Google Maps

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to add the InfoWindow in my code but it's not working. Map is showing perfectly but when i click the markers on map InfoWindow is not appearing. I also want to get the time in InfoWindow from MYSQL database. Please tell me how can i do this and what is the problem my InfoWindow is not appearing. Here is my InfoWindow Code:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var contentString = 'content';
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',window.onload);
```

Marker:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: markerpos,
 map: map, icon: icon
});
```

Comment: Have you any error in your console ? It could help you...

Comment: no error appearing at all. here is my complete code without InfoWindow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179488/google-maps-with-php-mysql

Comment: You should create a http://www.jsfiddle.net with your whole code instead of posting sample in various SO questions...

Comment: You need to provide more context (enough code to reproduce the problem).  The code [here (the example in the documentation)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) works and is pretty similar to yours.

Comment: @geocodezip i have already saw this example my problem is different. my infowindow is not appearing on map

Comment: You didn't provided enough code to determine your specific problem.  The [code in the example I listed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) is pretty much the same as yours except for ordering and scope, neither of which you provide in your posted snippets of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/RJPKJ/1/

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){                       
var dataProperty = dataitem.property[i];     
latitudetest =dataProperty.latitude;
longitudetest = dataProperty.longitude;
var data= dataProperty.property_title;    
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudetest, longitudetest);
}
```